# Using Kivy Touchinput and Kivyfile

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I'm using python and kivy.
My goal is to use the TouchInput and a kivy file.
The problem is that I have a request in the kv file:

```
<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        Image:
            source: 'image.png'
            on_touch_down: if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): root.doSomething()
```

Alone it works good, but after I added the TouchInput:

```
MainScreen:
   def doSomething:
     print("something")
   def on_touch_down(self,touch):
     print("down")
   def on_touch_move(self, touch):
     print("move")
   def on_touch_up(self, touch):
     pass
```

Just the TouchInput are recognized and the kivy file doesn't do it's request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to `on_touch_down()`, `on_touch_up()`, and `on_touch_move()` functions. Please refer to example for details and output.

## Snippets

```
    if super(MainScreen, self).on_touch_...(touch):
        return True
    if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        return False
    print('...')
    return True
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def doSomething(self):
        print("something")

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(MainScreen, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return False
        print('down')
        return True

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if super(MainScreen, self).on_touch_move(touch):
            return True
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return False
        print("move")
        return True

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if super(MainScreen, self).on_touch_up(touch):
            return True
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return False
        print("up")
        return True


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        Image:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            source: 'kivyLogo.png'
            on_touch_down:
                if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): root.doSomething()

        Image:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            source: 'raspberrypi.png'
```

## Output

[image: Img01]